# How do I get the top X number of users with the most Y in Sequelize ORM?

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to get the top 10 users with the highest follower count.  How do I do this using the Sequelize ORM?  Seems as though you would be using `SELECT TOP number|percent column_name(s)` with vanilla SQL,  but can't seem to find the same func with Sequelize.

Comment: You can use SubQuery in Attributes to get the follower count along with user info and then order desc for that value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Base on a document from [Sequelize about order & limit,](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#manipulating-the-dataset-with-limit-offset-order-and-group) we have a simple code

```
User.findAll({ 
    limit: 10 ,
    order: 'follower DESC'
})
```

Comment: Im looking at the documentation for sequelize, and for some reason this only returns the very TOP result, not a set of data... can you think of any reason why that is?

Comment: I figured it out, My problem laid in the fact that i was doing `const [results, metadata] = ....` this set the `results` variable equal to the first object, when in reality i wanted it to return the array of results. so i just cut out that in lieu of `const data = ....` and returned the data object. now it returns the the correct SQL query

Answer (score 1):

SELECT TOP doesn't work in every database vendor (maybe only Microsoft SQL Server?).  The  [sequelize doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll) describes "LIMIT" (used by MySql), which might work for your database.  Here's an example:

```
/*Find the 5 most relevant answers:*/
Answers.findAll({
  order: [[Sequelize.col(relevance_index),'DESC']],
  limit: 5
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

For v6, you may refer to [the doc](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#ordering)

```js
User.findAll({ 
    limit: 10 ,
    order: [['follower', 'DESC']]
})
```